# Unable to login to Amazon AWS custom AMI using custom keypair

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

I have successfully made an AMI and able to launch instances from this image from my AWS account successfully. However, as soon as I try to launch an instance from this AMI from some other AWS account specifying keypair other than whats in the AMI authorized_keys already, it doesn't let me login to instance with the new keypair(for obvious reasons). I am assuming that i need to implement some sort of mechanism to download the custom keypair specified in the instance creation wizard of Amazon AWS into the authorized_keys of the newly created instance.

Looking for hints on how this can be achieved !!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Take a loot at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CloudInit.

You need to set up the AMI with it and it will update the authorized key.

It's also available at other distros.

You can also make a script (for instance rc.local) and grab the value at:

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-keys/0/openssh-key
```

Amazon exposes lots of information through metadata.